# MAUI: How to reduce spacing between buttons

Tags: xaml, maui

How can i reduce the spacing between the buttons? I tried tweaking the `ItemSpacing` property but sadly it does nothing.

```
<CollectionView x:Name="TagsView"
                    Grid.Row="0">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="0"/>
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Text="{Binding Name}"
                        Padding="7"
                        FontSize="12"
                        CornerRadius="12" 
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        Clicked="TagButton_Clicked"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

[image]

Comment: it would help if you included more of your code so anyone looking at this can easily reproduce what you are showing and help you find a solution.

Comment: What exactly do you hope to achieve with this: HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand".

Comment: @H.A.H. it is to make sure the buttons expand in size so the text inside of them fits fully

Comment: Those options you have there, are used to determine how this button will fit in a parent container. More specifically - start/center/end/fill define alignment, and expand defines if it will occupy extra space if available.

Comment: Remove the padding.

Comment: @H.A.H. i see, i will try playing around with those values then

Comment: @H.A.H. removing the padding does help a bit, but how do i go about making the overall button smaller in that case. Reason i put padding is because it makes the button size smaller

Comment: You want 10 pixels? HeightRequest 10 and done. You want 10% of screen? Grid > RowDefinitions 1,9 (with asterisk) , VerticalOptions Fill, Vertical Options - fill > done.

Comment: As H.A.H. suggests, don't do `..AndExpand`. Also, do you need the buttons to be able to scroll to show more? If not, consider using `StackLayout` instead of `CollectionView`, with `Spacing="0"`. See [BindableLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout?view=net-maui-7.0).

Answer (score 4):

This is a `known issue` and it's been tracked in [[Windows] CollectionView ItemSpacing is not working](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4112). When setting the property `ItemSpacing` to **0**, the space between the items should have been reduced to **0**, however it doesn't work as expected. I would suggest that you can follow up it here:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4112.

AS an alternative workaround, you can use `HorizontalGrid` and set `HorizontalItemSpacing="0"` to remove the space between the buttons, however the `WidthRequest` of the button would be fixed. Here's the code snippet for your reference:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="TagsView"
                    Grid.Row="0">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                  <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  
                                   HorizontalItemSpacing="0" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Text="{Binding Name}"
                        FontSize="12"
                        CornerRadius="12" 
                        WidthRequest="100"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        BackgroundColor="AliceBlue"
                        TextColor="Black"
                        Clicked="TagButton_Clicked"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

**Update:**

The issue is now resolved, you can set `ItemSpacing="0"` whatever you want.