# .NET MAUI How to set CollectionView items Padding to 0

Tags: maui, collectionview, maui-windows

I can't set `padding` to `0` in items of `CollectionView` in MAUI.

In this example, I use `Data` and `Data[i].Color` as follow:

```xml
<CollectionView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" 
    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"
    ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button 
                Clicked="Button_Clicked" 
                WidthRequest="10" 
                HeightRequest="10" 
                BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

My Buttons has `Width` 10 and `Height` 10, and there is space between my Buttons. Only set Button `Width` more than 100 can I see no space between my Buttons, but 100 is too large.

I tried to set `Padding` or `Margin` in `Button`, and `WidthRequest` in `CollectionView`, but it didn't work.

How can I remove the space?

I tried ItemSpacing:

```xml
<CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <LinearItemsLayout 
        Orientation="horizonal"
        ItemSpacing="0" />
</CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
```

But fail.

Answer (score 1):

You want to set the space between buttons to `0` in `CollectionView`. And this is a `known issue` and it's been tracked in [Windows CollectionView ItemSpacing is not working](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4112). When setting the property ItemSpacing to `0`, the space between the items should have been reduced to `0`, however it doesn't work as expected.

For more details, you can refer to [MAUI: How to reduce spacing between buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74368780/9644964).